# C# Windows Form formclosing error

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, formclosing

i am pretty newbie for coding. Here is i am having a problem:

```
private void pano_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Uygulamadan çıkış yapmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?", "Çıkış", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

My purpose with this code block to ask user "are sure to quit" but unfortunetly when i close the application, i got notification window for 3 times? Is there any idea why thats happening or any solution?

Thanks a lot.
Nuri.

Comment: Start by removing the code for the Yes condition.It is unnecessary. If you do nothing the form will close by itself.

Comment: Dear Steve then application will not ask to user "Are you sure?". I just tried code as;

DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Uygulamadan çıkış yapmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?", "Çıkış", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            Application.Exit();

it asked "are you sure" but still appears notification window for 2 times and also end the application even if you will click "No"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as Steve pointed out, remove the 'Yes' part - if not explicitly canceled, the event will close that form as a result of clicking.

Now, for the problem of yours. Seems like your alert is called twice. I was able to solve that easily by making a `static bool close_alert_shown`, and when the first alert is shown, set it to true so that the next alert won't pop up.

Final code looks like that:

```
            if (close_alert_shown) return;
            close_alert_shown = true;
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Uygulamadan çıkış yapmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?", "Çıkış", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                close_alert_shown = false;
            }
```

And on the top of the form (before the `public Form1()` contructor line):

```
    static bool close_alert_shown = false;
```

Comment: Dear Yotam where i should declare "Application.Exit();"?

Comment: @NuriEngin No where. Clicking the exit button on the window bar closes the window. You don't have to do that. The `FormClosing` event does not actually close the form, but is invoked just before the form is closed. So, if you don't set `e.Cancel` to `true`, the event will not be cancelled, so the form will close.

Comment: Dear @Yotam if i'll change the "e.Cancel" to false then it will keep behavior as i am not aspected. As well with your suggestion after ending application  it keeps Debuging on IDE and therefore i should keep Stop Debuging on VS. So thats why i need "Application.Exit();"

Comment: "after ending application it keeps Debuging on IDE" - well, if clicking the close button and the application is still being debugged in the IDE, either you have another opened form, or another unstopped thread that is not declared as `IsBackground`

Answer (score 0):

What i suspect is when application is exiting, it is again calling form closing since we have subscribed for that event. I assume, simple fix would be unsubscribe from the event before calling exit.

```
this.FormClosing-=Form1_FormClosing;
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: Dear Praveen your suggestion works well and it behaves as i suspected but the thing i have another form name of Form2 and when end the application on Form2, "Yes" behavior worked well but "No" did not cancel closing process and it ended the application. Why is that or have can i overcome this situtation because totaly i'll have 7 forms in application.

Comment: is there any idea?

Comment: Where did u unsubscribe the event? unsubscribe only in "Yes" . when user selects "No" do the usual.

Comment: Thats exactly same what i did and somehow now it asks 2 times again when you end the app in Form2 window :/ 

`DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Uygulamadan çıkış yapmak istediğinizden emin misiniz?", "Çıkış", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.FormClosing -= pano_FormClosing;
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (dialog == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }`

Comment: Can you tell me your application structure? What is the form2 you are talking about?

Comment: @Preveen so there is a form name of "Dashboard" and a button on this form which gets you to another form name of "Team Member"